# GPIO Buttons on PiTFT With PIGPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I just added an Adafruit 2.2" PiTFT to my RPi 3 and I'm having problems with the four buttons it includes. I started using GPIO but had a lot of issues with the callbacks firing repeatedly or when nothing was pressed, I did however get the impression all four buttons worked as I was getting interrupts for each.

I switched to PIGPIO and have followed examples online, this is working fine for the button on GPIO17 but does nothing for any of the other three. I thought maybe only the first one "took" so I've tried assigning the callbacks in different orders or removing some but with no luck whatsoever. Is there something wrong with my code (copied from other examples online) that stands out to any of you?

Pressing the 17 button prints out the text as expected, none of the others do anything.

Ultimately this will run in a loop capturing temperature and humidity readings and logging them, my plan is to use the buttons to close down the program, close the program and shutdown the Pi and a couple of other ancillary tasks.

```
import pigpio
import time

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pi = pigpio.pi()
        the_pins = [
                    {"pin":17, "handler":self.btnHandler17},
                    {"pin":22, "handler":self.btnHandler22},
                    {"pin":23, "handler":self.btnHandler23},
                    {"pin":27, "handler":self.btnHandler27}]

        for x in the_pins:
            pin = x["pin"]
            self.pi.set_glitch_filter(pin, 20000)
            self.pi.set_mode(pin, pigpio.INPUT)
            self.pi.callback(pin, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, x["handler"])
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    def btnHandler17(self,pin,level,tick):
        print("Button 17 Pressed",pin,level,tick)

    def btnHandler22(self,pin,level,tick):
        print("Button 22 Pressed",pin,level,tick)

    def btnHandler23(self,pin,level,tick):
        print("Button 23 Pressed",pin,level,tick)

    def btnHandler27(self,pin,level,tick):
        print("Button 27 Pressed",pin,level,tick)

myButtons = Buttons()
```

Comment: If I use this code (posted by I think the PIGPIO author) I get a response from GPIO27 that shows the rising and falling edges being detected with a "tick" value such as 881205281 or similar. Does this imply I need to "tune" the glitch or noise filters in some way? I'm going to try removing the glitch filter from my code and see what happens.

Comment: Okay... it appears I need to clean up better, testing with this code https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124744#p836949 seems to give me responses for each button however the results seemed (at first) to be unpredictable. If I use that script after running my script it gets funky, I suspect I need to cleanup better to release the interrupts/callbacks in my script otherwise they hang around and interfere.

Answer (score 0):

After some comparisons and testing my code is now working, it seems that the issue was related to setting the interrupts/callbacks and not cleaning up (cancelling) them afterwards. The code below now fires the callback once per button press (I changed it to RISING_EDGE, with EITHER_EDGE it will fire on press and release if that's what you're wanting.

```
import pigpio 
import time 
btn17=17 
btn22=22 
btn23=23 
btn27=27 

def btnHandler17(pin,level,tick):
    print("Button 17 Pressed",pin,level,tick) 

def btnHandler22(pin,level,tick):
    print("Button 22 Pressed",pin,level,tick) 

def btnHandler23(pin,level,tick):
    print("Button 23 Pressed",pin,level,tick) 

def btnHandler27(pin,level,tick):
    print("Button 27 Pressed",pin,level,tick) 

pi = pigpio.pi() 

if pi.connected:
    pi.set_pull_up_down(btn17, pigpio.PUD_UP)
    pi.set_mode(btn17, pigpio.INPUT)
    cb17 = pi.callback(btn17, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, btnHandler17)

    pi.set_pull_up_down(btn22, pigpio.PUD_UP)
    pi.set_mode(btn22, pigpio.INPUT)
    cb22 = pi.callback(btn22, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, btnHandler22)

    pi.set_pull_up_down(btn23, pigpio.PUD_UP)
    pi.set_mode(btn23, pigpio.INPUT)
    cb23 = pi.callback(btn23, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, btnHandler23)

    pi.set_pull_up_down(btn27, pigpio.PUD_UP)
    pi.set_mode(btn27, pigpio.INPUT)
    cb27 = pi.callback(btn27, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, btnHandler27)

    time.sleep(30)

    cb17.cancel()
    cb22.cancel()
    cb23.cancel()
    cb27.cancel()
    pi.stop() 
else:
    print("Unable to connect PIGPIO, exiting")
    exit(0)
```